# Optional Validators for same control with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to implement a form with a field, this field has got several validations. The field will be correct if only one of the validators is correct. For example:

```
this.formBuilder.group({ 
  field: new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern('xx'), Validators.pattern('yy'), Validators.pattern('zz')]),
});
```

How can i implement it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of validators that would work that way? Cause the 3 in your example do not make sence with what you are trying to achive. Else you could create a custom validator which checks these diiferent rules.

Comment: Yes, the validators are with patters (Validator.pattern('')). When One of the validators are correct, the field validation is correct.

Comment: create an unique **custom validator** that check if the value match RegExpr with some RegExpr

Comment: Can you show me a simple example @Eliseo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Validators.compose() and combine logical operators between them:

```
this.formBuilder.group({ 
  field: new FormControl("", Validators.compose(
        [Validators.pattern('xx') || Validators.pattern('yy') || Validators.pattern('zz')])),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Francesco M. is correct. There's another way using regex in [Validators.pattern](http:///https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern):

```
this.formBuilder.group({ 
    field: new FormControl("", Validators.pattern(/(xx)+|(yy)+|(zz)+/)])),
});
```